# WooCommerce - get_order() is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, global-variables, helper

I'm trying to create a function that will retrieve an order by its ID. For some reason I can't get the WooCommerce global function `get_order` to work. I'm passing a valid order `id` to the function and trying to print it out to verify that it's working. The function has been placed in my `functions.php` file.

```
function getWC_order_details($id){
    global $woocommerce;

    $order = get_order( $id );

    print "<pre>";
    print_r($order);
    print "</pre>";
}
```

I have tested echoing other data out of the function without a problem.

Comment: And how did you use that function ? More detail requires here ..

Comment: `<php getWC_order_details(466); ?>`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've tried to improve the wording in your question to make it more clear to others what the issue you are encountering is. If you can link to any documentation for `get_order`, that might make it easier for those not familiar with WooCommerce to answer your question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all make function like this :

```
function getWC_order_details($order_id) { 
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    var_dump($order);
}
```

After that, use it with some `woo_commerce` **action** or **filter**.

```
function use_after_cart_table(){
    getWC_order_details(40);
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_table', 'use_after_cart_table' );
```

So after adding any product to the cart, you will see after cart table that there is one **array** containing all the details.

**NOTE** : You can use any other action or filter and you can find them [here](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/).

**EDITED:**

```
function getWC_order_details($order_id) { 
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    //var_dump($order);
    $order_shipping_total = $order->get_shipping();
    $order_shipping_method = $order->get_shipping_methods();
    var_dump($order_shipping_total);//Use it for debugging purpose or to see details in that array
    var_dump($order_shipping_method);//Use it for debugging purpose or to see details in that array

    $_order =   $order->get_items(); //to get info about product
    foreach($_order as $order_product_detail){
        //var_dump($order_product_detail);
        echo "<b>Product ID:</b> ".$order_product_detail['product_id']."<br>";
        echo "<b>Product Name:</b> ".$order_product_detail['name']."<br><br>";
    }
    //var_dump($_order);
}
```

Comment: Thanks the first part is what I needed. This function isn't for the cart or customers. It's part of a larger function I'm working on for when an order status changes to processing. I thought "WC_Order" would include everything about the order. Any idea how to get the products, name, and some shipping details from an order id?

Comment: You meant the products that are in that particular order only ...right ?

Comment: yes, only the information for that particular order.

Comment: I've been able to get all the shipping info I need, just working on getting the product name. Example: $order->shipping_first_name

Comment: The method 'get_shipping()' doesn't exist anymore, see the methods you can use here: https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html

Answer (score -1):

Try this. It might be useful to you.

```
function getWC_order_details($id)
{
   $array = WC_API_Orders::get_order( $id, $fields );
   print "<pre>";
   print_r($order);
   print "</pre>";
}
```

Source:
File name: woocommerce/includes/api/class-wc-api-orders.php

Comment: Didn't work, but thanks for trying. I did try that originally.  
  
`$order = WC_API_Orders::get_order( $id, $fields );`