# Woocommerce wp_query get order by ID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, foreach, orders

I am trying to produce a plain output of order data. First step is a WP_QUery (perhaps) so I write this code;

```
$args = array (

    'post_type'  =>'shop_order',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'any',
    //'p' => $post_id,

);    

$order_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $order_query->have_posts() ) :
  $order_query->the_post(); 

  echo the_ID();
  echo ' : '; 
  the_title();
  echo '<br/><br/>';

endwhile;
```

It obliging products a list of all orders, if I set the `'p' => $post_id` where `$post_id` is a valid post ID, the query returns nothing.

Any idea why, hive mind?

Alternatively is there  a Woocommerce way of producing a plain page with a layout like;

```
Order ID: 836
Order Status: ....
```

I assumed a WP_Query would be the obvious way but it is appearing like getting woocommerce order data is anything but straightforward.

Comment: As background, I have a Filemaker database that parses emails from a Romancart shopping solution, I could. of course, parse the order email from Woocommerce but I thought I'd be a bit cleverer and pass the data via a webpage. ESS is, of course, the best solution but it is also very programming intensive.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/28847572/1182891

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update 2**

To get the order data for one order, you don't need `WP_query`. You can use directly:

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$order->id; // order ID
$order->post_title; // order Title
$order->post_status; // order Status
// getting order items
foreach($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_values){
    // Getting the product ID
    $product_id = $item_values['product_id'];
    // .../...
}
```

---

**Update 1**

You should try this, as with **`array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses()`** you will get all order statuses and with **`'numberposts' => -1,`** all existing orders.

Here is an alternative way (without WP_query or you can use thoses args in the WP_query array):

```
$customer_orders = get_posts( array( 
    'numberposts'    => -1,
    'post_type' => 'shop_order',
    'post_status'    => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ) 
) );

// Going through each current customer orders
foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {

    // Getting Order ID, title and status
    $order_id = $customer_order->ID;
    $order_title = $customer_order->post_title;
    $order_status = $customer_order->post_status;

    // Displaying Order ID, title and status
    echo '<p>Order ID : ' . $order_id . '<br>';
    echo 'Order title: ' . $order_title . '<br>';
    echo 'Order status: ' . $order_status . '<br>';

    // Getting an instance of the order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Going through each current customer order items
    foreach($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_values){
        // Getting the product ID
        $product_id = $item_values['product_id'];
        // displaying the product ID
        echo '<p>Product ID: '.$product_id.'</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: `'post_status'=>'any'` does the trick, returning all posts was not a problem. Returning one post was my goal, see my answer above. But thanks anyway for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The strict answer to this question is change `'p'=>$post_id'` to `'post__in' => array($post_id)`

...but the real answer, should anyone be treading this path, is that parsing the email is so much easier, woocommerce has done most of the work for you. There are other pratfalls along the way; 1. The post is protected and the order notes are in the excerpt so can't be displayed ( I could move them to meta but...) 2. The order items are within comments and have to be looped then parsed to produce meaningful output, so I might as well parse the email direct.

Comment: It's worth noting, because moving Woocommerce data to Filemaker is a thing people may want to do, that the fact that a single Woocommerce order is a tangle of interrelated table entries means any solution is going to be complicated and that the order email may be the best ordered summary of the full data set from an order that there is.

Comment: Your question was very unclear… I didn't understand you was trying to call one order. you should better use directly  this `$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );` … no need of a query… then if you `print_r($order)` you will see that you can get everithing… I have updated my answer 2 times.